# IntelliJ Built-in TypeScript Compiler Command Line Options

Tags: intellij-idea, typescript, built-in

I have such C:/project/test.ts file:

```
import $ = require('jquery');
console.log($);
```

And I have placed jquery.d.ts file in: C:/jquery.d.ts

Using file watcher (with additional compiler arguments: --module amd C:/jquery.d.ts) file test.ts compiles successfully.

Using built-in compiler (with the same arguments: --module amd C:/jquery.d.ts) file test.ts doesn't compile. Error:

```
Error:(1, 20) TS2307: Cannot find external module 'jquery'.
```

Of course, I could define reference path test.ts file like this:

```
/// <reference path="C:/jquery.d.ts" />
```

After that - it compiles fine using both compilers. But its not convenient in big project. Would be better to define reference path just in one place (compiler arguments).

So how to define reference path using built-in TypeScript compiler command line options?

Answer (score 0):

> Would be better to define reference path just in one place (compiler arguments).
>   So how to define reference path using built-in TypeScript compiler command line options

You would include these *with your project*. Download directly from github or use `tsd`.

> I have large project with more than 100 .ts files, so defining reference path directly in each of files - bad solutio

Basically create a `globals.d.ts` file and `///<reference` these files *once*. Then you can just reference `globals.d.ts` and these get referenced *implicitly*.

Comment: I have downloaded all required d.ts files, but how to tell compiler where they are placed? I have large project with more than 100 .ts files, so defining reference path directly in each of files - bad solution.

Comment: I agree, that would be a solution. But I'm curious, why using file watcher compiler there is possibility to define reference to d.ts file and using built-in compiler - not possible. So maybe there is some other approach to achieve this?

Comment: Not at the moment. But soon you will be able to use `tsconfig.json` : https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript/blob/master/docs/tsconfig.md